# Join corresponding elements of 2 array columns by a delimiter in Azure Data Explorer to create a 3rd column

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

Azure Data Explorer table has 2 columns with array of same size. I want to add a new column that joins ith index of both arrays with underscore to create new array of same size.

`zip()` function can only create array of array with each element being an array of 2 of type `[ array1[i], array2[i] ]`.

I want each element of new column array as `array[i]_array2[i]`.

e.g. Column arr1 = [ 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', arr2 = ['10', '20', '30']
I want to create a new column 'Out' = [ 'A1_10', 'A2_20', 'A3_30']

Input table:

```
datatable (Val:int, Arr1:dynamic, Arr2:dynamic)
[ 1, dynamic(['A1', 'A2', 'A3']), dynamic(['C1', 'C2', 'C3']), 
  2, dynamic(['B1', 'B2']),       dynamic(['D1', 'D2'])
]
```

Expected table:

```
datatable (Val:int, Arr1:dynamic, Arr2:dynamic, Out:dynamic )
[ 1, dynamic(['A1', 'A2', 'A3']), dynamic(['C1', 'C2', 'C3']), 
     dynamic(['A1_C1', 'A2_C2', 'A3_C3']),
  2, dynamic(['B1', 'B2']), dynamic(['D1', 'D2']), 
     dynamic(['B1_D1', 'B2_D2'])
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
datatable (Val:int, Arr1:dynamic, Arr2:dynamic)
[ 1, dynamic(['A1', 'A2', 'A3']), dynamic(['C1', 'C2', 'C3']), 
  2, dynamic(['B1', 'B2']),       dynamic(['D1', 'D2'])
] 
| mv-apply Arr1, Arr2 on (
 extend Out = strcat(Arr1, "_", Arr2)
 | summarize Arr1 = make_list(Arr1), Arr2 = make_list(Arr2), Out= make_list(Out)
)
```

| Val | Arr1 | Arr2 | Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [ "A1", "A2", "A3" ] | [ "C1", "C2", "C3" ] | [ "A1_C1", "A2_C2", "A3_C3" ] |
| 2 | [ "B1", "B2" ] | [ "D1", "D2" ] | [ "B1_D1", "B2_D2" ] |